# T-Mobile Galaxy S 2 not seeing my app on the market

Tags: android, google-play

I have a device that is not seeing my app on the market. It is a Galaxy S II from T-Mobile. However, other devices can see it and it is listed as compatible in my Developer Console. The only obvious difference is that the owner loaded the new version of Gingerbread early to the device.

Manifest:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="inc.rufus.repair"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".RufusRepairToolActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="RufusRepairToolActivity$SecondaryReciever">
        <intent-filter> 
           <action android:name="inc.rufus.REPAIR_CONTINUED" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

I have looked at other similar problems, but nothing seems related (the app is very small, etc).

The real problem is the device belongs to my boss, so it really doesn't matter how many other devices it runs on.

Device Information:

Type: Galaxy S II (SGH-T989)
Carrier: T-Mobile
Android Version 2.3.6 (GINGERBREAD.UVKL1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enabled copy protection when publishing it? If so, uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

search by the package name.

the marketplace search has been very wonky

Comment: No results found. However on my Droid X a search for inc.rufus.repair finds it.

Comment: I can see it with my droid X2 with 2.3.4, and from reading the specs from the S2, the only difference is the front facing camera, which wouldn't be an issue, and the internal memory size, mine is 4gig and the S2 is 1gig

Comment: oh, and mine has a dedicated HDMI port, which again I don't think would be an issue, just putting it out there

Comment: Wait, does his phone have an SD card installed? the 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission> might not allow ones without SD cards mounted to see it.

Comment: he has installed the app via eclipse and it works. so it really shouldnt be a permissions problem

Answer (score 0):

For one reason or another reducing the minSDK to 1 allowed him to see the application. I do not understand why this would possibly be the case, but that's an issue for another day I guess.